# assign value for function and run on separate button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function somefunction(input) {
        $('div').html(input);
    }

    $("#assign").click(function () {
        //assign the value only
        somefunction("from assign to putput")
    });

    $("#output").click(function () {
        //run the function
        somefunction();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="assign" value="assign" />
<input type="button" id="output" value="output" />
<div></div>
```

How to assign a value on a function in one button and run that function on another button?

Any suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the value to a variable  outside the function scope.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var assignedvalue = "";
    function somefunction() {
        $('div').html(assignedvalue);
    }

    $("#assign").click(function () {
        //assign the value only
        assignedvalue = "from assign to putput";
    });

    $("#output").click(function () {
        //run the function
        somefunction();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure about using global variables but i always read that it is not a good practice to use global variables.

Comment: You should not use them if not needed. But this is typically a situation where you should use them, and it is the most convenient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use global variable instead of assigning values in function?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var input = "";
    function somefunction() {
        $('div').html(input);
    }

    $("#assign").click(function () {
        //assign the value only
       input = "from assign to putput";
    });

    $("#output").click(function () {
        //run the function
        somefunction();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="assign" value="assign" />
<input type="button" id="output" value="output" />
<div></div>
```

If you don't want to use global variables you can assign value to div attribute first, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function somefunction() {
        $('div').html($('div').attr('temp-value'));
    }

    $("#assign").click(function () {
        //assign the value only
       $('div').attr("temp-value","from assign to putput");
    });

    $("#output").click(function () {
        //run the function
        somefunction();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="assign" value="assign" />
<input type="button" id="output" value="output" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure about using global variables but i always read that it is not a good practice to use global variables

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var input="";//Global Variable initially assigned as empty
    function somefunction(input) {
        $('div').html(input);
    }

    $("#assign").click(function () {
        //assign the value only
        input="Some Value";//Assigning the global variable
    });

    $("#output").click(function () {
        //run the function
        somefunction(input);
        input="";//Clear the global variable after the success of 'somefunction'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="assign" value="assign" />
<input type="button" id="output" value="output" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: i can see two answers with this kind of solution. i don't know if you are just copying from them or you didn't see their answer.